# On `gcc` 11, how to change the prefix of `.gcno` files when using `--coverage` so they match what `gcov` expects?

Tags: c, gcc, code-coverage, gcov, gcc11

I'm adding code coverage on a C project of mine. The process I'm following is this:

```
# compile a .c file, expecting two new files "a.out" and "main.gcno"
gcc --coverage main.c

# run executable to get coverage data, expecting to create a new "main.gcda" file
./a.out

# use `gcov` to get formatted reports
gcov main.c
```

When I'm using `gcc` on version `10.3.0`, this all works as expected without issues. When using `gcc` with version `11.1.0` however, both the `main.gcno` and `main.gcda` files have a different name, which breaks the flow as explained below.

Using `gcc --coverage main.c` produces two files, `a.out` and `a-main.gcno`. Then running the executable with `./a.out` creates a new file `a-main.gcda`. Notice the prefix `a-` on the coverage files. When running the next command `gcov main.c`, I get the following error:

```
main.gcno:cannot open notes file
main.gcda:cannot open data file, assuming not executed
```

Because it is looking for the files `main.gcno` and `main.gcda`, but it can't find them.

Why does the new version of `gcc` do that? Everything I read online assumes that the output of the compiler should be in sync with `gcov` when run on the same source file. I couldn't find anywhere a way to change the output name of coverage files.

In case it helps, I also noticed the `a-` prefix depends on the output name. So if an output name is specified (`gcc --coverage main.c -o test`) then the coverage files will have that as prefix (`test-main.gcno` and `test-main.gcda`).

I've also tried manually renaming the files to remove the prefix, and `gcov` seems happy with that. The problem is that I'm trying to automate the process, and I'd like a more robust way than trying to guess what output name the compiler uses for coverage files.

For reference, I'm also using `gcov` on version `11.1.0`. It's not clear to me if that's related to the `gcc` being the same version.

Comment: I'd check the bug reports for 11.1 and the release notes for 11.2. This seems like a simple oversight that would be quickly reported and fixed.

Comment: @user3386109 I had a look at [GCC 11 Release Series](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-11/changes.html), and the only thing I could spot about code coverage were some optimisations, unless I missed it. I'll have a look on what's the best way to report it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does the new version of gcc do that?

See the [release notes for GCC 11](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-11/changes.html), specifically the third bullet of the Caveats which starts "Naming and location of auxiliary and dump output files changed".

> Everything I read online assumes that the output of the compiler should be in sync with gcov when run on the same source file. I couldn't find anywhere a way to change the output name of coverage files.

As it says in the release notes, the `-dumpbase` option is what you want. To remove any prefix, use `-dumpbase ''`

<strike>I'm not sure whether `gcov` should have been updated, or if the gcc-11 change should not have affected the coverage files.</strike> **Edit:** This is behaving [as](https://gcc.gnu.org/PR103666) [expected](https://gcc.gnu.org/PR104677).

Another solution is to compile and link in two separate steps:

```
gcc --coverage main.c -c
gcc --coverage main.o
```

This way the coverage data files do not get the prefix, and `gcov` finds them as expected.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I've tested it and it works as described. If you don't mind me asking, would using `-dumpbase ''` mess with different/older compilers? I tried it with `clang` for example, and it ignores it but still works as expected. The reason I'm asking is because this is planned to be part of a CD/CI flow, and might run on a number of different machines.

Comment: Not sure, sorry.