# make GCC11 behave like GCC10 for gfortran .gcda and .gcno files

Tags: gfortran, codecov

GCC11 seems to have broken the output behavior of .gcno and .gcda files.

Instead of being placed in the compilation directory (ie.e directory where I launch the compilation command from) with the filename matching the f90, just with a changed extension, to storing them inside the directory where the source is with an extended filename.

I've tried experimenting with -dumpfile and -dumpdir options, but I just want the old behavior back so that it works better with codecov.

I looked at this [On `gcc` 11, how to change the prefix of `.gcno` files when using `--coverage` so they match what `gcov` expects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71245957/on-gcc-11-how-to-change-the-prefix-of-gcno-files-when-using-coverage-s) but it didn't help. -dumpfile didn't keep the filenames the same and dumpdir didn't move them to where they were.

Thanks